# UITableViewRowAction behaves unpredictably

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have this following code which would take care of the right swipe in a tableViewCell, Its working fine when the user right swipe on the correct cell which has the discussionURL, if the user right swipe on the cell which does not have this URL then UITableViewRowAction return an empty array. Okay, After selecting a cell with no URL, then i am not able to select any other tableViewCell, i cant even right swipe. I know i miss something here.

Please help me out to figure it out.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let discussion = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Discussion") { action, index in
        self.loadTheDiscussionPageInWebViewController(indexPath.section, index: indexPath.row)
    }

    if let _ = self.allDatas[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].discussionUrl {
        print(" BUTTON \(discussion)")

        return [discussion]
    } else {
        print("NO BUTTON")

        return []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not return empty action array. Instead implement `tableView:indexPath:` function to return true only for your cell that has discussion URL in it. Something like this (ensure below return statement returns a `Bool`):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
     return self.allDatas[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].discussionUrl
}
```

Then call your `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let discussion = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Discussion") { action, index in
    self.loadTheDiscussionPageInWebViewController(indexPath.section, index: indexPath.row)
    return [discussion]
}
```